# Могу ли использовать streamreader как стандартный поток ввода с >>

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

У меня есть программа которая читает текстовый файл и обрабатывает его принимая значения через Fstream in; и далее in >> x >> y >> n; Адрес файла вбивал ручками через консоль с двойными слешами.
Потребовалось перенести программу на windows forms пока научился только читать файл построчно через streamreader и openfiledialog.
Могу ли я как-то применить синтаксис стандартеных потоков ввода\вывода через >>.

Comment: уточню, могу ли я как-то открыть файл так, чтобы можно было его читать как поток ввода через синтаксис >> x >> y >> z;
уж больно он показался мне удобным.

Comment: Программа на Windows Forms -- это C#?

Comment: Не обязательно C#. Win forms и появился раньше c# вроде как

Comment: использую widows forms для c++ в VS2015